# Flutter Android resource linking failed and Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin-android']

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

Opened a project after 2 months, got null-safety error changed some plugins, and upgraded others, one thing led to another and now I am stuck at this error!

Tried Flutter clean and deleting the build and .gradle folder but nothing worked.

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1801 in debug mode...
    lib\main.dart:1
    3
    registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
       > Android resource linking failed
         C:\Users\Dell\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b94a6b46912fba96397655c3d1ce5de0\play-services-ads-lite-19.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-38:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
    
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 8m 59s
    The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
    Building plugin audioplayers...
    Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Dell\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\audioplayers-0.18.2\android\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'audioplayers'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin-android']
   > The current Gradle version 4.10.2 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 5.3 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
2

Exception: The plugin audioplayers could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.` it looks like you have to update your gradle version to one of the ones listed here

https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Troubleshooting

3.3.3

3.4.3

3.5.4

3.6.4

4.0.1

it looks like you need to downgrade your gradle version since you're using 4.10.2